# Are there any surface treatments that would make calcium usable for metallurgy?

Tags: physical-chemistry, metallurgy

Calcium is the best conductor for its weight, but the soluble powdery oxide makes it impractical for use in power lines.  Are there any surface treatments or alloying processes that could help?

(Calcium phosphates are reasonably insoluble, but I don't know how well they bind to the metal underneath; lithium-aluminium alloys are used in a lot of aerospace applications despite the strong reactivity of lithium with air and water)

Comment: This has been flagged as "too broad", and I lack the expertise to decide whether or not it is such. Still, I'd appreciate it if someone could comment on their close vote.

Comment: Calcium is so reactive that (1) cladding seems to be the only chance, (2) getting it pure is going to be horrendously expensive.  Also if you were to try alloying you'd lose some of the conductivity you want.

Comment: That sounds like an interesting current surge situation, since Ca melts so low, burns oh so bright and produces toxic fumes. Using Ca for electric conductance sounds impractical, unnecessary and possibly hazardous.

Comment: Utilities have investigated the use of sodium for electrical transmission (which sounds similar). But they used thick wires coated with something like polyethylene which would ,presumably, also work with calcium. But the problem of what happens if the wire breaks still exists.